# Why isn't this working (remove property that match object property)

Tags: javascript, object

Why isn't this working? Implement the remove property function which takes an object and propety name, and removes it if they match and return true if not false

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {

  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  for (const key of keys) {

    if (key === obj[prop]) {

      delete obj[prop]

      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what "if they match" means here. `prop` isn't really used as a *property name* in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `obj[prop]` is the value. Compare the `key` to `prop`:

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  for (const key of keys) {
    if (key === prop) {
      delete obj[prop]

      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

However, since object properties are unique, you don't need to iterate them. Use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if a property exists:

```
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if (prop in obj) {
    delete obj[prop]

    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

Comment: How does in work? is it something just for objects?

Comment: I've added a link that explain `in` in depth. The description of `in` is: The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate the keys to remove a single property.

```js
function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
  if(typeof obj[prop] !== "undefined") {
    delete obj[prop];
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete obj[prop] will delete the property if it exists.
```

```js
let o = {a:1,b:2};
removeProperty(o, 'a')

function removeProperty(obj, prop) {
   delete obj[prop];
}

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score -1):

So, just fixed the if to

if (obj[key] === obj[prop])

and it worked. Can someone explain the difference between this and the code on the question

Comment: This is the wrong solution. If you have multiple properties that have the same value, this doesn't work. You need to look for the *key*, not the value of the property. See Ori Drori's answer.